# user's hostname issue while staring a weblogic server

Tags: linux, ipv4, hostname, username

When login with putty with any user say 'oracle' the prompt is showing the prompt as follows:
`oracle@/?` instead of actual hostname like `oracle@myhost`which is why I am unable to start my server as its going to lookup for ip with the hostname `/?` to IPV4 which its not able to resolve.

How can I revert the user to use the hostname `oracle@myhost` instead of `oracle@/?`
?

Comment: What you mean by "*my user is showing as follows: `oracle@/?`*"? Is that the output of `id`?  Or the contents of `$USER`?  And what does the hostname have to do with anything?

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the response, I have edited the question to add more clarity of the problem I am facing